# Groovy Check Multiple objects for null

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, is there an elegant ( and clear ) way to check ***multiple objects*** for null ..example

```
    def a = null
    def b = null
    def c = null
    def d = null

    // Is there a simpler ( more elegant ) version of this line of code
    if ( a== null || b== null || c == null || d == null ) {
      print "Null detected"
    }
```

Comment: Put them in a list and use `any`?

Answer (score 0):

> In Groovy, is there an elegant ( and clear ) way to check multiple objects for null

It may depend on your preference and what you find to be elegant, but the code you show there is idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks ...I ended up using following ... for me, seems a little more readable/elegant                
    if ( null in [a,b,c,d] )                                                                                                    .comments welcome.

Comment: That is fine.  Be aware that you are creating a `List`, populating it and then iterating through it to inspect elements to find a `null` one.  If the performance isn't a concern, what you said there is fine.  Another approach that is similar would be `[a,b,c,d].any { it == null }`.  Well done!

Comment: Part of the challenge with asking for elegant is you might find elegance in something like `[a, b, c, d].any { it == null }` for a number of reasons, but you could find elegance in `if(a == null || b == null ...)` for different reasons.